# CoffeeScript interactive

Tags: coffeescript, linux-mint

I read from this [source](http://autotelicum.github.io/Smooth-CoffeeScript/interactive/interactive-coffeescript.html) that I am able to run the interactive environment using `coffee -r ./prelude` on my console. However, it is not working on my Linux Mint 15.

Yes, CoffeeScript is installed. I can enter a form of interactive mode by simply typing `coffee` on my console (albeit only one-liner expressions).

I received the following error and apparently option -r is not recognized.

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/optparse.js:51
        throw new Error("unrecognized option: " + arg);
              ^
Error: unrecognized option: -r
    at OptionParser.exports.OptionParser.OptionParser.parse (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/optparse.js:51:19)
    at parseOptions (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:464:29)
    at Object.exports.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:55:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee:7:41)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

Does `coffee -r ./prelude` give me another kind of interactive mode (multi-line expressions perhaps)? Is it possible that this is an OS problem?

Comment: CoffeeScript version 1.6.3, still the same after update.

Comment: `coffee -h` does not show any kind of `-r` argument. What exactly do you expect from running the `-r ./prelude`? Maybe the documentation you linked is outdated?

Comment: It might be possible. I am reading about CoffeeScript using [Smooth CoffeeScript](http://autotelicum.github.io/Smooth-CoffeeScript/interactive/interactive-coffeescript.html). This resource is either outdated or the author implemented his own CoffeeScript. Since I am still new, I am not experienced enough to determine this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first `coffee -r` / `coffee --run`  was used to run scripts.

It got deprecated from **0.5.3** ([issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/211) / [commit](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/commit/f4cd0bdf29b0c57563e02a6e6b444bb64e12674d)).

---

Then `coffee -r` / `coffee --require` was used to require modules.

It was removed since **1.5.0** ([commit](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/commit/33140259b85dc52a4dad3b89f171db9a0917ef4d) / [issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2852)).

@jashkenas said about that:

> **--require** was originally for when we were encouraging folks to "extend" (read, monkey-patch) the compiler's inner classes to their own ends. It doesn't really work very well, so we removed it. Instead, you can just require() within your files as usual, if you're running them directly with coffee. If you're not running them directly with coffee, then it shouldn't matter.

As for now, Coffescript version is **1.6.3**, This book was written when it was only **1.2.0**.

---

I can recommend these online books:

- https://leanpub.com/coffeescript-ristretto/read
- http://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/

Answer (score 0):

The `prelude/prelude.coffee' file starts with:

```
# Usage: require './prelude' or on commandline: coffee -r ./prelude
# This prelude is a learning environment for 'Smooth CoffeeScript'.
```

Evidently the `-r` option meant `require`. Whether that was a commandline option at an earlier time (`smooth` is several years old), or is part of a custom `coffee`, I don't know.  In any case it isn't an option for the current `coffee`.  Use `coffee -h` to see current usage.

So what you need to do is enter interactive coffee with `coffee`, and then `require <the prelude.coffee location>`.  `prelude` does some tricks, and actually puts its functions in the global namespace.  With it it will be easier to follow the examples in the book, but it shouldn't been used as a regular part of your `coffee` setup.

`show` the most common utility function that `prelude` defines.  In many cases you can use `console.log` instead of it.